# possible C code implementation ideas for a given shell script(related to ffmpeg)

Tags: c, shell, ffmpeg, netcat

The shell script i'm trying to implement goes like this,

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while [ 1 ]
    do
       nc -l 1234 | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -vcodec mpeg4 -s qcif -f m4v -y pipe:1 | nc localhost 1235
    done
```

what it does is to simply take in a stream of video input through network and do live video transcoding(with ffmpeg of course!) and streaming back the video through the net. my question is how should i go by to implement this functionality in a clean C code. i know i can use popen() to pipe such a command from a c code but i would like to do better. may be with sockets and staff... any pointers are appreciated.

AskLearnDo.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script works fine, why would you bother wasting the time to redo it in C? You're still going to need to use popen() to communicate with a ffmpeg sub program unless you want to figure out how to call their library to achieve equivalent functionality (or reimplement the ffmpeg transcoding, which is beyond the scope of a SO question).

And yes you would need to use sockets - http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ was a good starting point for me years ago.